# Form1 closes after ShowDialog for Form2

Tags: c#, forms, hide, show, showdialog

I have 2 forms. I'm opening form2 with `ShowDialog()`, but then when I close it (by hiding it) form 1 disappears for few seconds, but if I use show to open form 2 then this does not happen.

I need to use `ShowDialog()`, how could I fix disappearance of form 1 after form 2 closes ?

I tried to use `Form1.Show()` right after I close form 2 with `Hide()` but does not work.

Form1

```
private void p0_igra2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        this.CenterToScreen();
        imevislice.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Form2

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")  
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Polje more biti izpolnjeno"); 
        else  
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();   
            ime = textBox1.Text;  
            if (radioButton1.Checked)  
                izbrane_besede = "SLO";   
            else
                izbrane_besede = "ENG";
            this.Hide();
            form1.Show();
            form1.namehangman(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the full code? That behavior doesn't sound right.

Comment: There posted code, I hope it does not bother you that everything is not in english

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually closing `Form2`...

Comment: I just hide it, because later user can open it again so I do not use dispose

Comment: That would be your problem

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Just replaced hide with dispose and still after I close form 2, form 1 disappears for about 2-3 seconds.

Comment: You wouldn't call `Dispose` directly. You want `Form.Close`. Your form shouldn't *ever* be not visible; so if it is, you need to show the code thats hiding it.

Comment: Tried Form.Close and still same result. Form is visible all the time, I used Show() so I would force it to stay visible right after from2 closes, but it sill disappears

Comment: That is very odd. Can you replicate on a simple 2 form solution (no other code, just a show button and a dismiss button on the popup)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a form with `ShowDialog` you need to **close** (`Form.Close`) it when you are done. `ShowDialog` starts a modal dialog; which means the calling function will not continue execution until the form is closed.

Using `Show` can fix this, but you didn't say what wasn't working with that approach.

In general, `ShowDialog` is pretty cheap; you should be able to just close the form correctly and you won't run into any issues.

Comment: Show works fine, but I want to use ShowDialog so form1 gets "deactivated". And I replaced hide with dispose and form 1 still disappears. Perhaps I can get same deactivation somehow if I use Show ? Turning enabled to false is not really the same.

Comment: @Miko What do you mean by "Deactivation"? `ShowDialog` shouldn't ever make the form disappear.

Comment: Not to disappear, I mean that when form2 opens up you cant click anything in form1 till form2 is open and you cant minimize form2. For example if you open Visual studio and then TOOLS->Options = that result I want to get

Comment: @Miko `ShowDialog` is the right way to handle that. I would try making a MCVE of it as I noted in my other comment.

Comment: Oh yeah I have just created that. I it works perfectly somehow. Could there be reason for disappearence of form1 that I have a lot of code + I generate some random with SQL ?

Comment: @Miko None that I can think of. I would add your code back in to the working code one piece at a time; and see which one causes the problem. If its not obvious *why* that code is causing it; ask here!

Comment: I fell kind stupid now, form doesnt hide actually but it jumps into background visual studio and other applications cover my application somehow

Comment: @Miko There you go! Glad you were able to get it fixed